# Setting up a condition to verify if the 20th day of the month exist then do something, otherwise go to next workday

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, weekday

I have formulated workdays for a month and need to display in the column next to those days data conditional to, for this instance:

if the day is the 20th, i.e: Day(Cell) = 20, do the thing on the 20th.

Some months though do not have a 20th, so I want the condition to evaluate if the 20th exists, else go to next workday and do what it was supposed to do on the 20th.

Current formula used is :

```
=IF(DAY(A16)=20;"do the thing on the 20th";"")
```

in the snapshot, April 2019 does not have a 20th of the month and therefore nothing is displayed in column C, I would want it to be displayed on the next workday which would be the 22nd of April.

[image: snapshot of current result since no 20th exist]

Comment: You can make a `VLOOKUP` table and use approximate match. Also, do you mean **workday** (I.E. Monday through Friday) or do you mean **day** as in weekends also. If a month doesn't have a 20th workday, it won't have a 22nd..... terminology here may confuse people so lets clarify that first :)

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that if the 20th falls on a weekend, you want to convert to the next workday? I.E. if the 20th is Sat, go to Mon?

Comment: actually the column A is only a list of weekdays. my condition has to meet the 20th of the month among those workdays, but if it does not exist, to go to next workday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shift Sat, Apr 20, 2019 to Mon, Apr 22, 2019 subtract a day and add a workday.

```
=IF(A16=WORKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A16); MONTH(A16); 19); 1); "do the thing on the 20th"; "")
```

If you don't like the `DATE(YEAR(A16); MONTH(A16); 19)` date construction, `EOMONTH(A16, -1)+19` accomplishes the same thing; i.e. the 19th day of the month and year in A16.